# Unable to update Integer field in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to update an 'integer' fields in SQLite database by adding 1 to it. So it is `X = X+1`

Following is my code

```
  public synchronized void updateStatistics(List<String> correctWords,
            List<String> facedWords, int wordListNumber, boolean flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] tableLastNames= {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        String tableName = "WordList_"+tableLastNames[wordListNumber];


        if(flag)
        {
            //First update 'FacedWords' row

            Toast.makeText(context, "Faced Words Length: "+facedWords.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Correct Words Length: "+correctWords.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try
            {
                for(int i=0;i<facedWords.size();i++)
                {
                    String query = "update  "+ tableName+" set NumberOfTimesEnglishWordShowed=NumberOfTimesEnglishWordShowed+1 where EnglishWord = ' "+(facedWords.get(i)).trim()+"'";
                    database.execSQL(query);
                }

                for(int i=0;i<correctWords.size();i++)
                {
                    String query = "update   "+ tableName+" set NumberOfTimesEnglishWordCorrected=NumberOfTimesEnglishWordCorrected+1 where EnglishWord = ' "+(facedWords.get(i)).trim()+"'";
                    database.execSQL(query);
                }

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Word: "+, duration)
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Update error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }



    }
```

I am using SQLite database browser to see the things in my database, and I noticed the above code has updated nothing! There is no error as well!  In case you need, following is the required part from the table

```
String createDatabaseQuery = "create table WordList_A(" +
                    "ID integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    +"NumberOfTimesEnglishWordShowed integer,"

                    +"NumberOfTimesEnglishWordCorrected integer,");";
```

The update query I used is similar to the MS SQL update query, so I am not sure whether that way is working with SQLite. Why my code is not updating anything?

Comment: Is the leading space in `' "+(facedWords.get(i)).trim()+"'` on purpose? It seems wrong...

Comment: @Heuster: Great! This is it! Thank you! Since you found the issue first, I would like to mark your answer as the answer. Please be kind enough to provide your answer as an Answer

Comment: Tnx, but just mark the other answer as accepted. It's not a competition :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have extra "space" in your where clause :

```
where EnglishWord = ' "+(facedWords.get(i)).trim()+"'"
```

so replace it with :

```
where EnglishWord = '"+(facedWords.get(i)).trim()+"'"
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for the answer. It works! I already gave you a +1